# Using regex to delimit text

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with a text-file with more than 1000 documents inside. Most of the document is very similar, starting and ending with same layout. I'm trying to split the text in an array, and each item would be a document:

```
let documents = [
  [], <- doc1
  [], <- doc2
  ....
];
```

To achieve this, i'm using a  giant regex, that get the number of total pages of a doc (i have this info in the first page), and takes everything => `[\s\S]*?` <= until the last page. is not working very good, cause some docs may not have the last page, so is catching two docs instead of one.

http://regexr.com/3dk54

Here, the regex is catching two docs, but if you delete the Z6: 0 u will see the problem.

Is it possible to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: `text.split(/^(?=,MINISTÉRIO)/m)` should work pretty well for the sample text you posted.

Comment: http://regexr.com/3dk5d This is causing infinite. Can you show me a working example?

Comment: Don't test this with regexr. This is an expression specifically designed to split your string. It matches nothing.

Comment: So, would this regex split this text in two docs?

Comment: No, in 12. Your sample text contains 12 pages.

Comment: I don't want split the pages, i want split the docs, in this example i have 2 docs: http://regexr.com/3dk54

Comment: Well, use `text.split(/^(?=MINISTÉRIO)/m)`, then.

Comment: Is working. How this works??

Comment: What `string.split()` does should be clear, and `/^(?=MINISTÉRIO)/m` is the regular expression that matches the string position immediately before the word `MINISTÉRIO` at the start of a line. Read about how this works here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result with a match?

Comment: What would be the point if it is the same result? Apart from that, you want to split a string. So use the right tool, i.e. the split function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple regex should be fine. Here im using %start% and %end% to delimit each document. Replacing it with your current delimiter should work fine aswell.

```
"your-whole-document-content".match (/(%start%)(.*?[\n\r]?)*?(%end%)/g)
```

If your delimiter is using any special character, dont forget to scape them.

EDIT

```
"your-whole-document-content".match (/(MINISTÉRIO)[\s\S]*?(?=,\1)/g)
```

Comment: http://regexr.com/3dk5g Like this? Can u take off the Z6 from the first match and check out?

Comment: I just edited with a new regex that i believe its working for what you need.